# How to avoid Cucumber from recreating or refreshing the app context

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber-java, spring-cache

My cucumber tests get the spring boot context refreshed on each pass, I have some database cache being done and it is killing the performance of the compilation process.

My abstract test is marked as @SpringBootTest(defined_port) with a @ContextConfiguration(loader=SpringBootContextLoader.class).

I already tried adding DirtiesContext but it did not work... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the latest Cucumber (v5.7.0) to make Cucumber aware of your test configuration you can annotate a configuration class on your glue path with `@CucumberContextConfiguration` and with one of the following annotations: `@ContextConfiguration`, `@ContextHierarchy` or `@BootstrapWith`. If you are using SpringBoot, you can annotate configuration class with `@SpringBootTest`

For example:

```java
import com.example.app;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration; 

@CucumberContextConfiguration 
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class) public class 
CucumberSpringConfiguration { }
```

You can then `@Autowire`  components from the application context into any step definition file. No further spring configuration is needed. For example:

```java
package com.example.app;

public class MyStepDefinitions { 

 @Autowired
 private MyService myService;

 @Given("feed back is requested from my service")
 public void feed_back_is_requested(){ 
    myService.requestFeedBack(); 
  }
}
```

The only requirement is that both `MyStepDefinitions` and `CucumberSpringConfiguration` are both in a package that is on the glue path. So either you have configured `@CucumberOptions(glue="com.example")` explicitly or your test runner class is in the same package as your step definition (`com.example`).

You can find more information in the `cucumber-spring` module in github.
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-spring

Comment: that's actually interesting. so you are scanning the entire classpath for `CucumberSpringConfiguration` annotated classes, correct? I mean I see no other way to do this. It's also interesting, how this glue is later processed, would take a look at the code if you are willing to share a hint. thank you.